# JSF Primefaces Master Page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, master-pages

I am planning to build a master page, for example in my page I want only my center layout change when I click to something.
How can I make this happen ?
Thanks
Burak

Comment: You have different methods to achieve that. Do you want different bookmarkable urls to be shown? Or just a main central frame which will be updated via ajax? You can have a look at the [PF layout component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf).

Comment: Yes only the main central frame will be updated via ajax

Comment: Then create a central pane (you could use `ui:include` to make it include dynamic content) and update it.

Answer (score 1):

An example

**Your master page**

```
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<p:layout fullPage="true">

<p:layoutUnit  position="north"  header="header" >
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit  position="south"  header="footer" >
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit   position="west" header="menu" >
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit   id="centerLayout" header="content" position="center">
    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">              
    <ui:include src="#{navBean.page}.xhtml" />                  
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Your central part**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

</ui:composition>
```

**Your managed bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="navBean")
@SessionScoped
public class NavBean implements Serializable {
private String page;

//constructor
//initiate `page` with appropriate value
//getters and setters

}
```

To change the central part, just change the `page` String accordingly, and then update the form with ajax.